# Error: use of class template 'map' requires template arguments (C++)

Tags: c++, dictionary, oop, lru

For the following code snippet, I get an error. Unable to understand it's cause. (IDE: Eclipse)
I'm trying to build an LRU cache (a very basic implementation), I've used a list and 2 maps, one to store the position of an element (key,value) in the list and the other to store the mapping between a key and value.

```
*Error: Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -D__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ -D__cplusplus=201103L -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF"Cache.d" -MT"Cache.o" -o "Cache.o" "../Cache.cpp"
../Cache.cpp:22:2: error: use of class template 'map' requires template arguments
        map
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/map:898:28: note: template is declared here
class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS map
                           ^
../Cache.cpp:26:1: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
};
^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [Cache.o] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.*

09:45:46 Build Failed. 3 errors, 0 warnings. (took 659ms)
```

PS: This is for competitive coding purposes (Kindly pardon the naming of variables)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<list>
#include<map>


using namespace std;

class Cache{
public:
    int capacity;
    int current_capacity;
    map<int, list<int> :: iterator >maps;
    map<int,  int >key_val;
    list< int >dll;

    Cache(int cache_size){
        capacity = cache_size;
        current_capacity = 0;
        map<int, list<int> :: iterator >maps;
        map<int,  int >key_val;
        list< int >dll;
    }
    
    int get(int key){
        list<int> :: iterator it ;
        if(maps.find(key) != maps.end() and maps[key] != nullptr){
            it = maps[key];
            dll.erase(it);
            dll.push_back(key);
            it = dll.end() - 1;
            maps[key] = it;
            cout << "key: " << key << " " << "value: " << key_val[key] << endl ;
            return key_val[key] ;
        }
        else{
            cout << "ERROR: KeyError" << endl ;
        }
        
    }
    
    void put(int key, int value){
        list<int> :: iterator it ;
        if(current_capacity < capacity){
            if(maps.find(key) == maps.end() or maps[key] == nullptr){
                dll.push_back(key);
                it = dll.end() - 1; 
                maps[key] = it;
                current_capacity += 1 ;
            }
            else if(maps.find(key) != maps.end() or maps[key] == nullptr){
                it=maps[key];
                dll.erase(it);
                dll.push_back(key);
                maps[key] = dll.end() - 1 ;
                key_val[key] = value ;
            }
            
        }
        else{
            if(maps.find(key) == maps.end() or maps[key] == nullptr){
                dll.push_back(key);
                it = dll.end() - 1; 
                maps[key] = it;
                key_val[key] = value;
                int least_recent =dll.front();
                maps[least_recent] = nullptr ;
                dll.pop_front();
                        
            }
            else if(maps.find(key) != maps.end() or maps[key] == nullptr){
                it=maps[key];
                dll.erase(it);
                dll.push_back(key);
                maps[key] = dll.end() - 1 ;
                key_val[key] = value ;
            }
            
            
            
            
        }
        
    }

};

int main(){
    
    Cache cache_obj = Cache(3);
    cache_obj.put(1,2);
    cache_obj.put(2,4);
    cache_obj.put(3,3);
    cache_obj.put(4,4);
    cache_obj.put(2,5);
    cache_obj.get(2);
    cache_obj.get(8);

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: `maps[key] != nullptr` The type of `maps[key]` is an iterator, not a pointer. An iterator cannot be compared to nullptr.

Comment: `dll.end() - 1` won't work since list iterators are not random-access iterators. Make it `std::prev(dll.end())`

Comment: maps.find won't return an null pointer, maps.find doesnt return a pointer at all, seems like using java logic in c++ programs, maps will return an iterator, if no item is found it will return end()

Comment: `get` exhibits undefined behavior by way of reaching the closing brace without encountering a `return` statement. It's declared to return `int`, but it's possible for it to not return anything.

Comment: *PS: This is for competitive coding purposes (Kindly pardon the naming of variables)* -- The questions asked by the "competitive coding" sites are meant for persons who already know the computer language they will use to answer the question -- well enough to not have to ask anything about the computer language itself.  Those sites are not there to teach C++.  If your strong language is python, then the question should be answered in python.  If you want to answer the question in C++, you need to learn C++, and then go back and answer the questions, with the only issue being the logic used.

Comment: `maps[least_recent] = nullptr` won't work for the same reason `maps[key] != nullptr` won't work - iterators are not pointers.

Comment: I would advice you to explore the difference java objects and c++ objects, c++ objects cannot be set as null unless those classes explicitly allow so.

Comment: Also in your constructor: `map<int, list<int> :: iterator >maps; map<int,  int >key_val;list< int >dll;` do nothing, since they are not the same variables as the member variables, just temporary variables within the constructor.